# JavaScript - Selecting all non-inline Input Text Box elements using Pure JS

Tags: javascript, forms, input, queryselector

I have a couple of input elements on a page. There are two `radio` buttons and three `text box` elements. I am only interested in the text box elements that are on their own line, in other words not inline. Also, not that I said text box elements, not text elements. Because I should be able to select both `input[type=text]` and `input[type=number]` fields.

This has to be a PURE JavaScript solution, so CSS and jQuery won't work.

Looking at the HTML, you can clearly see that the inline `<input>` tags are preceeded by `<label>` tags. So one idea is to find ALL input elements, transform them into an array, and search that array for items that are not preceeded by label tags.

This code doesn't work but even if it did, there should be an easier way to find this.

```js
let selectedTextBoxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text], input[type=number]'))
                             .filter(i => i.previousElementSibling.tagName != 'label');

selectedTextBoxes.forEach(textBox => { textBox.classList.add('highlight') });
```

```css
.highlight { background: gold; }
```

```html
<h2>Select an Option</h2>

<div class="label-group">
  <label>A</label>
  <input type="radio"></input>
</div>
<div class="label-group">
  <label>B</label>
  <input type="radio"></input>
</div>
<div class="label-group">
  <label>Other</label>
  <input type="text"></input>
</div>

<h3>Now type in a number between 1 and 99</h3>
<input type="number"></input>
<h3>Type in a comment</h3>
<input type="text"></input>
```

Comment: First of all I don't get what is  inline `<input>`? Is it the input elements that are in the `<div class="label-group">`? And second, what is the end goal? You select some (or all of the input elements) and then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JavaScript `.querySelectorAll` uses [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), which are powerful. This is the tool for the job.

In your specific case, below selects the `<input>` elements that are not preceded by a `<label>` element but not using that specific logic.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("body > input").forEach(function(input){input.classList.add("highlight")});
```

```css
.highlight {
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2>Select an Option</h2>

<div class="label-group">
  <label>A</label>
  <input type="radio"></input>
</div>
<div class="label-group">
  <label>B</label>
  <input type="radio"></input>
</div>
<div class="label-group">
  <label>Other</label>
  <input type="text"></input>
</div>

<h3>Now type in a number between 1 and 99</h3>
<input type="number"></input>
<h3>Type in a comment</h3>
<input type="text"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select the input elements that is not preceded by label element you can use the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) in combination with the [sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

```css
form :not(label)~input {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<h2>Select an Option</h2>
<form name="form01">
  <div class="label-group">
    <label>A</label>
    <input type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="label-group">
    <label>B</label>
    <input type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="label-group">
    <label>Other</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <h3>Now type in a number between 1 and 99</h3>
  <input type="number">
  <h3>Type in a comment</h3>
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

And this CSS selector can also be used in the querySelectorAll() method:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('form :not(label)~input');
console.log([...elements].map(elm => elm.name).join(','));
```

```css
form :not(label)~input {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<h2>Select an Option</h2>
<form name="form01">
  <div class="label-group">
    <label>A</label>
    <input name="radio01" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="label-group">
    <label>B</label>
    <input name="radio01" type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="label-group">
    <label>Other</label>
    <input name="text01" type="text">
  </div>

  <h3>Now type in a number between 1 and 99</h3>
  <input name="number01" type="number">
  <h3>Type in a comment</h3>
  <input name="text02" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<input>` has no end tag  and by default is `inline-block` unless you change it's CSS property `display` value. As far as CSS and jQuery not working is an odd assumption because CSS determines whether `<input>` is `inline` or not and jQuery is based on JavaScript.

So instead, **Example A** is a solution to this question:

> *"Using plain JavaScript, how can I target only `<input>` with `type="text"` or `"number"` and only when they are not preceded by a `<label>`?"*

**Example B** is a solution to this question:

> *"Using plain JavaScript, how can I target only `<input>`s not within `div.label-group`?"*

Both solutions lead to the same result, which is the last two `<input>`s being highlighted.

**Example A**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(input => {
  if (!input.type || input.type === "text" || input.type === "number") {
    if (!input.previousElementSibling.matches("label")) {
      input.classList.add("highlight");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2>Select an Option</h2>

<div class="label-group">
  <label>A</label>
  <input type="radio">
</div>
<div class="label-group">
  <label>B</label>
  <input type="radio">
</div>
<div class="label-group">
  <label>Other</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<h3>Now type in a number between 1 and 99</h3>
<input type="number">
<h3>Type in a comment</h3>
<input type="text">
```

**Example B**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(input => {
  if (!input.parentElement.matches(".label-group")) {
    input.classList.add("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2>Select an Option</h2>

<div class="label-group">
  <label>A</label>
  <input type="radio">
</div>
<div class="label-group">
  <label>B</label>
  <input type="radio">
</div>
<div class="label-group">
  <label>Other</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<h3>Now type in a number between 1 and 99</h3>
<input type="number">
<h3>Type in a comment</h3>
<input type="text">
```